# Is there any list of Magento compatible country codes?

Tags: magento, sms, country-codes

Looking for a country code list for calling or texting the countries specified in the Magento core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the full list of short name codes and the corresponding country code number.  Listing in PHP array format so you should be able to do stuff with it in loops for formatting in any other way.

https://gist.github.com/bubach/9887414

Also inline (long):

```
$countryCodes = array(
    array (
        'country_code' => 'AF',
        'phone_code' => '93',
    ), 
    array (
        'country_code' => 'AX',
        'phone_code' => '35818',
    ), 
    array (
        'country_code' => 'NL',
        'phone_code' => '31',
    ), 
    array (
        'country_code' => 'AN',
        'phone_code' => '599',
    ), 
    array (
        'country_code' => 'AL',
        'phone_code' => '355',
    ), 
    array (
        'country_code' => 'DZ',
        'phone_code' => '213',
    ), 
    array (
        'country_code' => 'AS',
        'phone_code' => '685',
    ), 
    array (
        'country_code' => 'AD',
        'phone_code' => '376',
    ), 
    array (
        'country_code' => 'AO',
        'phone_code' => '244',
    ), 
    array (
        'country_code' => 'AI',
        'phone_code' => '1264',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'AQ',
        'phone_code' => '672',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'AG',
        'phone_code' => '1268',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'AE',
        'phone_code' => '971',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'AR',
        'phone_code' => '54',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'AM',
        'phone_code' => '374',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'AW',
        'phone_code' => '297',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'AU',
        'phone_code' => '61',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'AZ',
        'phone_code' => '994',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'BS',
        'phone_code' => '1242',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'BH',
        'phone_code' => '973',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'BD',
        'phone_code' => '880',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'BB',
        'phone_code' => '1242',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'BE',
        'phone_code' => '32',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'BZ',
        'phone_code' => '501',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'BJ',
        'phone_code' => '229',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'BM',
        'phone_code' => '1441',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'BT',
        'phone_code' => '975',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'BO',
        'phone_code' => '591',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'BA',
        'phone_code' => '387',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'BW',
        'phone_code' => '267',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'BV',
        'phone_code' => '47',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'BR',
        'phone_code' => '55',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'GB',
        'phone_code' => '44',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'IO',
        'phone_code' => '246',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'VG',
        'phone_code' => '1284',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'BN',
        'phone_code' => '673',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'BG',
        'phone_code' => '359',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'BF',
        'phone_code' => '226',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'BI',
        'phone_code' => '257',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'KY',
        'phone_code' => '1345',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'CL',
        'phone_code' => '56',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'CK',
        'phone_code' => '682',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'CR',
        'phone_code' => '506',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'DJ',
        'phone_code' => '253',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'DM',
        'phone_code' => '1767',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'DO',
        'phone_code' => '1809',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'EC',
        'phone_code' => '593',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'EG',
        'phone_code' => '20',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'SV',
        'phone_code' => '503',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'ER',
        'phone_code' => '291',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'ES',
        'phone_code' => '34',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'ZA',
        'phone_code' => '27',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'GS',
        'phone_code' => '500',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'KR',
        'phone_code' => '82',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'ET',
        'phone_code' => '251',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'FK',
        'phone_code' => '500',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'FJ',
        'phone_code' => '679',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'PH',
        'phone_code' => '63',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'FO',
        'phone_code' => '298',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'GA',
        'phone_code' => '241',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'GM',
        'phone_code' => '220',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'GE',
        'phone_code' => '995',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'GH',
        'phone_code' => '233',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'GI',
        'phone_code' => '350',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'GD',
        'phone_code' => '1473',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'GL',
        'phone_code' => '299',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'GP',
        'phone_code' => '590',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'GU',
        'phone_code' => '1671',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'GT',
        'phone_code' => '502',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'GG',
        'phone_code' => '44',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'GN',
        'phone_code' => '224',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'GW',
        'phone_code' => '245',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'GY',
        'phone_code' => '592',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'HT',
        'phone_code' => '509',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'HM',
        'phone_code' => '61',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'HN',
        'phone_code' => '504',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'HK',
        'phone_code' => '852',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'SJ',
        'phone_code' => '47',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'ID',
        'phone_code' => '62',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'IN',
        'phone_code' => '91',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'IQ',
        'phone_code' => '964',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'IR',
        'phone_code' => '98',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'IE',
        'phone_code' => '353',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'IS',
        'phone_code' => '354',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'IL',
        'phone_code' => '972',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'IT',
        'phone_code' => '39',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'TL',
        'phone_code' => '670',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'AT',
        'phone_code' => '43',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'JM',
        'phone_code' => '1876',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'JP',
        'phone_code' => '81',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'YE',
        'phone_code' => '967',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'JE',
        'phone_code' => '44',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'JO',
        'phone_code' => '962',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'CX',
        'phone_code' => '61',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'KH',
        'phone_code' => '855',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'CM',
        'phone_code' => '237',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'CA',
        'phone_code' => '1',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'CV',
        'phone_code' => '238',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'KZ',
        'phone_code' => '7',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'KE',
        'phone_code' => '254',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'CF',
        'phone_code' => '236',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'CN',
        'phone_code' => '86',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'KG',
        'phone_code' => '996',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'KI',
        'phone_code' => '686',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'CO',
        'phone_code' => '57',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'KM',
        'phone_code' => '269',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'CG',
        'phone_code' => '242',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'CD',
        'phone_code' => '243',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'CC',
        'phone_code' => '61',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'GR',
        'phone_code' => '30',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'HR',
        'phone_code' => '385',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'CU',
        'phone_code' => '53',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'KW',
        'phone_code' => '965',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'CY',
        'phone_code' => '357',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'LA',
        'phone_code' => '856',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'LV',
        'phone_code' => '371',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'LS',
        'phone_code' => '266',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'LB',
        'phone_code' => '961',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'LR',
        'phone_code' => '231',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'LY',
        'phone_code' => '218',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'LI',
        'phone_code' => '423',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'LT',
        'phone_code' => '370',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'LU',
        'phone_code' => '352',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'EH',
        'phone_code' => '21228',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'MO',
        'phone_code' => '853',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'MG',
        'phone_code' => '261',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'MK',
        'phone_code' => '389',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'MW',
        'phone_code' => '265',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'MV',
        'phone_code' => '960',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'MY',
        'phone_code' => '60',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'ML',
        'phone_code' => '223',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'MT',
        'phone_code' => '356',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'IM',
        'phone_code' => '44',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'MA',
        'phone_code' => '212',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'MH',
        'phone_code' => '692',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'MQ',
        'phone_code' => '596',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'MR',
        'phone_code' => '222',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'MU',
        'phone_code' => '230',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'YT',
        'phone_code' => '262',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'MX',
        'phone_code' => '52',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'FM',
        'phone_code' => '691',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'MD',
        'phone_code' => '373',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'MC',
        'phone_code' => '377',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'MN',
        'phone_code' => '976',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'ME',
        'phone_code' => '382',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'MS',
        'phone_code' => '1664',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'MZ',
        'phone_code' => '258',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'MM',
        'phone_code' => '95',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'NA',
        'phone_code' => '264',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'NR',
        'phone_code' => '674',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'NP',
        'phone_code' => '977',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'NI',
        'phone_code' => '505',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'NE',
        'phone_code' => '227',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'NG',
        'phone_code' => '234',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'NU',
        'phone_code' => '683',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'NF',
        'phone_code' => '672',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'NO',
        'phone_code' => '47',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'CI',
        'phone_code' => '255',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'OM',
        'phone_code' => '968',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'PK',
        'phone_code' => '92',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'PW',
        'phone_code' => '680',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'PS',
        'phone_code' => '970',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'PA',
        'phone_code' => '507',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'PG',
        'phone_code' => '675',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'PY',
        'phone_code' => '595',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'PE',
        'phone_code' => '51',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'PN',
        'phone_code' => '870',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'KP',
        'phone_code' => '850',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'MP',
        'phone_code' => '1670',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'PT',
        'phone_code' => '351',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'PR',
        'phone_code' => '1',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'PL',
        'phone_code' => '48',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'GQ',
        'phone_code' => '240',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'QA',
        'phone_code' => '974',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'FR',
        'phone_code' => '33',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'GF',
        'phone_code' => '594',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'PF',
        'phone_code' => '689',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'TF',
        'phone_code' => '33',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'RO',
        'phone_code' => '40',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'RW',
        'phone_code' => '250',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'SE',
        'phone_code' => '46',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'RE',
        'phone_code' => '262',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'SH',
        'phone_code' => '290',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'KN',
        'phone_code' => '1869',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'LC',
        'phone_code' => '1758',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'VC',
        'phone_code' => '1784',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'BL',
        'phone_code' => '590',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'MF',
        'phone_code' => '1599',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'PM',
        'phone_code' => '508',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'DE',
        'phone_code' => '49',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'SB',
        'phone_code' => '677',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'ZM',
        'phone_code' => '260',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'WS',
        'phone_code' => '685',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'SM',
        'phone_code' => '378',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'SA',
        'phone_code' => '966',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'SN',
        'phone_code' => '221',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'RS',
        'phone_code' => '381',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'SC',
        'phone_code' => '248',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'SL',
        'phone_code' => '232',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'SG',
        'phone_code' => '65',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'SK',
        'phone_code' => '421',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'SI',
        'phone_code' => '386',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'SO',
        'phone_code' => '252',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'LK',
        'phone_code' => '94',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'SD',
        'phone_code' => '249',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'FI',
        'phone_code' => '358',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'SR',
        'phone_code' => '594',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'CH',
        'phone_code' => '41',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'SZ',
        'phone_code' => '268',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'SY',
        'phone_code' => '963',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'ST',
        'phone_code' => '239',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'TJ',
        'phone_code' => '992',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'TW',
        'phone_code' => '886',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'TZ',
        'phone_code' => '255',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'DK',
        'phone_code' => '45',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'TH',
        'phone_code' => '66',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'TG',
        'phone_code' => '228',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'TK',
        'phone_code' => '690',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'TO',
        'phone_code' => '676',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'TT',
        'phone_code' => '1868',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'TN',
        'phone_code' => '216',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'TR',
        'phone_code' => '90',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'TM',
        'phone_code' => '993',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'TC',
        'phone_code' => '1649',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'TV',
        'phone_code' => '688',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'TD',
        'phone_code' => '235',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'CZ',
        'phone_code' => '420',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'UG',
        'phone_code' => '256',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'UA',
        'phone_code' => '380',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'HU',
        'phone_code' => '36',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'UY',
        'phone_code' => '598',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'NC',
        'phone_code' => '687',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'NZ',
        'phone_code' => '64',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'UZ',
        'phone_code' => '998',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'BY',
        'phone_code' => '375',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'VU',
        'phone_code' => '678',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'VA',
        'phone_code' => '39',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'VE',
        'phone_code' => '58',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'RU',
        'phone_code' => '7',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'VN',
        'phone_code' => '84',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'EE',
        'phone_code' => '372',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'WF',
        'phone_code' => '681',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'US',
        'phone_code' => '1',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'VI',
        'phone_code' => '1340',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'UM',
        'phone_code' => '1',
    ),
    array (
        'country_code' => 'ZW',
        'phone_code' => '263',
    )
);
```

Answer (score 3):

I want to share how to get the country to phone code mapping with a Magento built-in function.

```
$countryPhoneMapping = Mage::app()
    ->getLocale()->getTranslationList('territorytophone');

var_dump($countryPhoneMapping); //something like array( 'AC' => 247, 'AD' => '376', ... )
```

**Note:** The data is fetched from the *lib/Zend/Locale/Data/telephoneCodeData.xml* file. Perhaps to mention the list will not contain any 4-digit phone codes. But for my approach it was enough.

In my case I had to show in a dropdown only the phone codes of selected countries in the Magento backend under **System -> Configuration -> General -> Countries Options -> Allowed Countries**

```
function country2phoneMapping() {
    $options = array();

    $allowedCountries = Mage::getModel('directory/country')
        ->getResourceCollection()
        ->loadByStore()
        ->toOptionArray(); 

    $countryPhoneMapping = Mage::app()->getLocale()
        ->getTranslationList('territorytophone');

        foreach( $allowedCountries as $value => $label ) { // e.g. DE => Germany
            foreach( $countryPhoneMapping as $number => $territory ) { // e.g 49 => DE
                if ( strpos( $territory, $value ) !== false ) {
                    $options[$value] = '+' . $number;
                }
            }
        }

    return $options;
}
```

Comment: Well, that kind of sucks. For me at least. Also it would seem that my array is faulty on those countries with 4 or more digits, can't remember now exactly where I got the information. Possibly the added digits represent mobile-carrier code, since that was my primary use of it - sending texts. Great find, and thanks for sharing full backend-option-method. :)

Comment: Also `Mage::app()->getLocale()->getTranslationList('phonetoterritory')` to return an array based on `[country_code => phone_code]`

Answer (score -1):

you can get country list using directory modules
here the code below

```
 Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')
        ->load()->toOptionArray();
```

Comment: The question was about the country number for calling or texting, maybe I didn't make myself clear enough in the question. But the fact that I answered it myself should give you some clue that this is for googlers, and not for me. ;)

Comment: Will upvote because of the additional information value for the stray googler. :)